# Toner flaking off of printed paper on Ricoh MP5000

Tags: printer, printing, hardware-failure

I have a Ricoh Aficio MP5000 and I am having an issue, albeit an intermittent one, where you can flake the toner off of a printed page.  I imagine this has something to do with an error within the fusing unit.

However, since fusing units are a fortune, even on the eBays, and it can be parted out; does anyone have an idea about what aspect of the fusing unit I should look to replacing first?  Pressure roller?  Holder roller?  Hot roller?

Comment: are you sure its not the toner?

Comment: It was replaced less than a week ago - it was my first suspicion, but, unless both containers are bad, I don't think that's the issue.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: It could be multiple/various things, so replace the fuser unit.  It's a "unit" for a reason. :)  If it's too expensive, then replace the printer, if that's too expensive, stop printing, if you absolutely have to keep printing, then the fuser is not "too expensive". ;)  Have you called Ricoh yet?

Comment: I figure I would have to replace the fuser, I was just hoping that I could save a few company bucks by piece-mealing the repair.  I've called Ricoh, and, due to a long story involving the company that previously owned this machine, they are not an option for repair at this time.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: If both containers where cheap 3rd party toner they might both be bad =]

Answer (score 0):

A little old, but just in case someone comes hunting...

This is due to one of two things; either your machine is oversupplying toner onto the page, or (more likely) the fuser is not running at the correct temperature, the cause of which is fuser age, incorrect SP settings, or both.

I wouldn't replace individual components of the fuser, but if you did feel game, then make sure the unit has been out of the machine at least 24 hours, as the components inside stay hot longer than you'd expect.

Best of luck.